# List append and extend in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
marxes = ['Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo', 'Zeppo']
others = ['Gummo', 'Karl']
```

when i am appending marxes with others i am getting below result

```
marxes.append(others)
['Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo', 'Zeppo', ['Gummo', 'Karl']]
```

Now when i am trying to extend others with marxes

```
others.extend(marxes)
['Gummo', 'Karl', 'Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo', 'Zeppo', [...]]
```

when i am indexing others as `others[-1]` i am getting this

```
['Gummo', 'Karl', 'Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo', 'Zeppo', [...]]
```

even with `others[-1][-1][-1][-1]` i am getting this

```
['Gummo', 'Karl', 'Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo', 'Zeppo', [...]]
```

can any one tell me why this is happening , and how can i get the last element of others as marxes only

Comment: Please format your code properly. Use the insert code option to type code

Comment: Dude what do you exactly want ??? To exaplain the above results?

Answer (score 0):

when you call `others.extend(marxes)`, `marxes = ['Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo', 'Zeppo', others]`: you are extending the list `others` with a list that contains a reference to `others` already (you are creating a circular reference). that is what the `[...]` hints at.

to fix that you could append a copy of `others` in the first step:

```
marxes = ['Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo', 'Zeppo']
others = ['Gummo', 'Karl']

marxes.append(others[:])
others.extend(marxes)
```

(and as i do not exactly understand what you really want to achieve i can not tell you how to do that properly...)

Comment: can you explain it little bit more , my requirement is that I have a 2 list , I want to append list2 to list1 and then extend list 2 with list 1 element and then i want to access each element of list 2

Comment: please provide the desired output of your program. i do not really understand what you want in the end...